# Hugo Docsy SwaggerUI shortcode doesn't render the specs file

Tags: swagger-ui, hugo, hugo-shortcode, docsy

I'm trying to render an OAS file using [Hugo Docsy SwaggerUI Shortcode](https://www.docsy.dev/docs/adding-content/shortcodes/#swaggerui) but the rendered page doesn't contain the expected result.

Here is my `rest-api.md` file:

```markdown
---
title: "REST API"
linkTitle: "REST API"
date: 2021-02-21
weight: 2
description: >
  REST API described using OpenAPI Specification.
---

{{< swaggerui src="http://localhost:1313/access.yaml" >}}
```

And here is the rendered page:

[image: rendered page]

As you can see, the HTML contains the following script that tries to render the OAS file:

```js
  var resolveUrl = function () {
    var passedUrl = 'http:\/\/localhost:1313\/access.yaml';
    var baseUrl = '\/\/localhost:1313\/'.replace(/\/$/, '');
    if (passedUrl.startsWith('/')) {
      return baseUrl + passedUrl;
    }
    return passedUrl;
  };
  window.onload = function () {
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: resolveUrl(),
      dom_id: '#ohpen_swagger_ui',
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ]
    });
    window.ui = ui;
  };
```

It is to be noted that `http://localhost:1313/access.yaml` resolves successfully to `access.yaml` file.

What prevents the OAS file to be rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my mistake. The `type` must be set to `swagger` in the front-matter of the page.

The page must be as follows:

```markdown
---
title: "REST API"
linkTitle: "REST API"
type: swagger
date: 2021-02-21
weight: 2
description: >
  REST API described using OpenAPI Specification.
---

{{< swaggerui src="http://localhost:1313/access.yaml" >}}
```

> The OAS file can be referenced using relative path `/access.yaml` in case it is served by Hugo as a static file.